# .net Core get configuration of started application

Tags: c#, .net-core

How to get configuration of started application in C# .Net Core

I know that I can do it like that:

```
public static string Get_Configuration() {
      string conf = "Release";
#if DEBUG
       conf = "Debug";
#endif
      return conf;
}
```

But it doesn’t look very good, any ideas how to do it most beautifully?

[image]

Comment: That's not a "configuration". Are you looking for the "environment"? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Chek the [documentation on .NET Core configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2). It show how to read environment variables or command line parameters, and use those to load different configuration files. There's even a standardized environment variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` that can be used for this, although you can use any env variable you want. CodeCaster's link shows how that can be used to change the ASP.NET core bootstrap code.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ENV "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" show me Development or Production, but the configuration it is another option

Comment: @IgorCova it's not. You can use the very same methods to register different providers. In fact, many of the ASP.NET COre tutorials show how you can read different `aspsettings.{env}.json` where `env` is a varialbe set based on `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos check the question please - there I put image what I mean

Comment: What Visual Studio calls the "project configuration" is a collection of settings that also include whether or not to build in debug or release mode, and which conditional symbols to define. The names of these configurations cannot be accessed directly from code because they don't exist there -- but you can set any conditional compilation symbols you like, and checking those *is* properly done with `#if` / `#else` / `#endif` (and I recommend you use that pattern, and not the code you have now, to avoid missing cases).

Comment: @IgorCova that's the project's build configuration. It's not a .NET Core concept. It's not something that can be know at *run* time. Everyone that reads about just `Configuration` will think you're talking about the configuration system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess what you need is build platform.

Build platform is embedded in the DLL / EXE at the time of compilation.

I am not sure what is the purpose and what exactly should be input to the API you want to create.  Hence I am throwing couple of options which I believe would help you to solve the issue.

**Option 1: Use Assembly Attribute**

In this you can conditionally apply assembly configuration attribute to the assembly.
Then at runtime, you can check the assembly attributes applied to the DLL / EXE.

```
#if (Debug || DEBUG)
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("Debug")]
#else
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("Release")]
#endif
```

**Option 2: Using C# code**

There is a method is from [Scott Hanselman's](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToProgrammaticallyDetectIfAnAssemblyIsCompiledInDebugOrReleaseMode.aspx) blog which takes assembly name and decides if the assembly was built using Release mode.

```
public static int GetBuildType(string AssemblyName)
{
    Assembly assm = Assembly.LoadFrom(AssemblyName);
    object[] attributes = assm.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DebuggableAttribute), false);
    if (attributes.Length == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} is a RELEASE Build....", AssemblyName));
        return 0;
    }

    foreach (Attribute attr in attributes)
    {
        if (attr is DebuggableAttribute)
        {
            DebuggableAttribute d = attr as DebuggableAttribute;
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Run time Optimizer is enabled : {0}", !d.IsJITOptimizerDisabled));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Run time Tracking is enabled : {0}", d.IsJITTrackingEnabled));

            if (d.IsJITOptimizerDisabled == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} is a DEBUG Build....", AssemblyName));
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} is a RELEASE Build....", AssemblyName));
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 3;
}
```

**Option 3: PowerShell Script**

On the same blog, you can find some powershell scripts which can also be used.

Based on your purpose and ease, you can select any one of the option.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean environment if I'm not wrong.
Here's what you can do, in SolutionExplorer go to:

**Properties -> lunchSettings.json**

In your **launchSettings.json**, you'll find a json object which contain a section named **Profiles**.

Under profile add the environments you want.

For example, in the first place your Profiles will be like that:

```
  "profiles": {
"ProjectName.Development": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "api/Locations",
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
}}
```

Change your Profiles to be like this:

```
  "profiles": {
"ProjectName.Development": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "api/Locations",
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
},
"ProjectName.Local": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "api/Locations",
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Local"
  }
},
"ProjectName.Production": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "api/Locations",
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
  }
}}
```

After finishing. Add to your solution explorer:

***appSettings.Development.json***,

***appSettings.Local.json***,

***appSettings.Production.json***.

And add your configuration to these files.

Then you can navigate between your environments and run whatever you want from the tool bar as you can see in the following image:

[image]